# How to convert the .wav file to tfrecord file?

Tags: tensorflow, audio

I am new in the tensorflow part and hope someone can help me.

I've seen this document https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav and executed `tf.audio.decode_wav( contents, desired_channels=-1, desired_samples=-1, name=None )`
The only thing I've changed is the **contents**, changing to my `path name`.
But still get an error!

Any methods to convert it? And I want to output something like this. `.tfrecord-00000-of-00008`

Answer (score 0):

Read the .wav file into a string of bytes and then decode it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
wav_contents = tf.io.read_file("file.wav")
audio, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=wav_contents)
audio.shape
```

This example was borrowed from the TensorFlow [tutorial on reading audio files](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio#read_the_audio_files_and_their_labels).

Comment: Thanks, but the audio output is an array, not an tfrecord file.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with tfrecord files. Have you tried running this code?

Comment: Yes I have, it returns an array. But I need to export to a tfrecord file.